# How to write a function that adds elements of list using tail recursion?

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I need to write a function in OCaml that adds elements of two lists in two different recursions: simple and tail. I made one with simple:

```
let rec add1 a b = 
match (a, b) with
      ([], []) -> []
    | (head1::tail1, []) -> head1 :: add1 tail1 []
    | ([], head2::tail2) -> head2 :: add1 [] tail2
    | (head1::tail1, head2::tail2) -> head1 + head2 :: add1 tail1 tail2
;;
```

It works like this:

```
add1 [1;2;3] [4;5;6;7];;
```

This return:

```
int list = [5; 7; 9; 7]
```

`[1+4; 2+5; 3+6; 0+7]` : 0 is added to 7 because there are no element on such position in first list.

So, my question is:

How can I make it with tail recursion?

Comment: Do you have to handle the case where the 2 lists have different length ?

Comment: Yes I need, as in my first function I have to add 0 if there is no element on similar position in one of the lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to make this tail recursive is to build the result backwards and pass it along in the recursion and reverse it at the end.

```
let add1 a b =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | (xs, [])
    | ([], xs) -> List.rev_append acc xs
    | (x::xs, y::ys) -> loop ((x + y)::acc) (xs, ys)
  in
  loop [] (a, b)
```

Note: If one list is longer then the other then you don't need to add 0 to each element. The tail is already the result. So I use List.rev_append to reverse the accumulated values and append the remaining tail in one go.

Note2: List.rev_append can also append the empty list so no match for ([], []) is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Tail recursion consists in having recursive function that simply performs a call to themselves without any other operations.

The following factorial is not tail recursive, because the last statement does not perform a simple call to fact but require a multiplcation :

```
    let rec fact n = 
        if n = 0 then 1
        else n*(fact (n-1))
```

By using an accumulator you can make this function tail recursive, the last statement performs a call to fact and therefore can be compiled using a jump and not a call :

```
    let rec fact n r =
        if n = 0 then r
        else fact (n-1) (r*n)
```

And the usage :

```
    fact 5 1
```

For you list addition, you can proceed the same way if the 2 lists have the same length at least.

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys to problem solving in programming is breaking problems down. Can you get pairs of elements from two lists, with a default?

That's pretty straightforward.

```
# let rec combine lst1 lst2 default =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], [] -> []
    | [], y::ys -> (default, y) :: combine [] ys default
    | x::xs, [] -> (x, default) :: combine xs [] default
    | x::xs, y::ys -> (x, y) :: combine xs ys default;;
val combine : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a -> ('a * 'a) list = <fun>
# combine [1;2;3] [4;5] 0;;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 0)]
```

Now, if we add an accumulator variable to a locally scoped inner function, we can make this tail recursive. Because the work is done immediately and passed along in the accumulator argument to the next call to the function, `aux` is always in the tail position.

*We use `::` because it's a constant time operation. This builds the accumulated list up in reverse. It may seem tempting to use `@` to concatenate the new value to the end of the list, but this is a linear time operation, and using it in a loop gives us quadratic time complexity, so the function doesn't scale well for very large data sets.*

```
let combine lst1 lst2 default =
  let rec aux acc lst1 lst2 = 
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], [] -> List.rev acc
    | [], y::ys -> aux ((default, y) :: acc) [] ys
    | x::xs, [] -> aux ((x, default) :: acc) xs []
    | x::xs, y::ys -> aux ((x, y) :: acc) xs ys
  in
  aux [] lst1 lst2;;
val combine : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a -> ('a * 'a) list = <fun>
# combine [1;2;3] [4;5] 0;;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 0)]
```

Having these pairs, adding them is fairly straightforward as well.

```
# combine [1;2;3] [4;5] 0
  |> List.map (fun (a, b) -> a + b);;
- : int list = [5; 7; 3]
```

But `List.map` isn't tail-recursive (until [OCaml 5.1.0](https://ocaml.org/releases/5.1.0)) so we can similarly make `map` tail-recursive.

```
let map f lst =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs -> aux (f x :: acc) xs
  in
  aux [] lst
```

Having done this, the combination of the two simpler tail-recursive functions is itself tail-recursive.

```
combine [1;2;3] [4;5] 0
|> map (fun (a, b) -> a + b)
```